# I have a error with nodejs 0.10.2 + express 3.x + socket.io 0.9.11

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

nodejs : v0.10.2 and express 3.x and socket.io 0.9.11

I just try sample code on the socket.io like below.

http.js708
throw new Error(can't set headers after they are sent)

http://socket.io/#how-to-use

**Server side**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**client side - `index.html`**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

then I have an error message like on the picture.

[image]

Comment: How about showing us some of the code that's generating this error?

Comment: Please post the error message itself instead of a screenshot. Now other people searching for solutions to this problem won't find this.

Comment: I couldn't copy error message from shll window ..

Comment: I've change socket.io 0.9.11 to 0.9.13 than It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u 've to check the connection  was established r not after that u continue ur code

here some sample code

```
var app = require('express')()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(3000)    

io.on('connection',function(socket){
  console.log('connection..')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed socket.io 0.9.11 to 0.9.13 than It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check handler function in server side code. 
You are sending response muliple times, thats why it was giving error as headers sent already, as response was already sent & you are sending it again. Correct the code as below.

```
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
    }
  });
}
```